# jq: Add field to collection deep in nested structure, calculated from other fields at the same level

Tags: json, iterator, jq

I'm looking for someone who can give me a hint with jq here - it seems I'm missing out on something.

My JSON source would be similar to this:

```
[
    {
        "cluster": "one",
        "slots": [
            {
                "instances": [
                    {
                        "number": 0,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "A",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 4
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "B",
                                "unhealthy": 2,
                                "healthy": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "number": 1,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "B",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 6
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "C",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cluster": "two",
        "slots": [
            {
                "instances": [
                    {
                        "number": 1,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "A",
                                "unhealthy": 1,
                                "healthy": 9
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "C",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 10
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "number": 0,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "B",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 9
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "D",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 14
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I need would be a new "status" field in each innermost collection as the sum of the "healthy" and "unhealthy" states, like this:

```
[
    {
        "cluster": "one",
        "slots": [
            {
                "instances": [
                    {
                        "number": 0,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "A",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 4,
                                "status": 4
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "B",
                                "unhealthy": 2,
                                "healthy": 2,
                                "status": 4
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "number": 1,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "B",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 6,
                                "status": 6
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "C",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 2,
                                "status": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cluster": "two",
        "slots": [
            {
                "instances": [
                    {
                        "number": 1,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "A",
                                "unhealthy": 1,
                                "healthy": 9,
                                "status": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "C",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 10,
                                "status": 10
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "number": 0,
                        "services": [
                            {
                                "name": "B",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 9,
                                "status": 9
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "D",
                                "unhealthy": 0,
                                "healthy": 14,
                                "status": 14
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to iterate in this manner:

`jq '.[].slots[].instances[].services[] += { "status": ($iterator.healthy + $iterator.unhealthy) }'`

In all my attempts so far, I either couldn't access the elements at the same level for the calculation... or the rest of my data got dumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `|=` operator.

```
.[].slots[].instances[].services[] |= (.status = .unhealthy + .healthy)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed - thank you for pointing me in the right direction!